# Why JAVA required constructor?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, initialization

In JAVA if we can Initialize inside the class as.

```
class Emp2 {
    int salary=100;

    public static void main(String... s) {
        Emp2 e1=new Emp2();

        System.out.println(e1.salary);
    }
}
```

Then why we need constructor to do so? Plss help mee..

Comment: What if you don't know what you want the value to be at compile time?

Comment: Try to create two employees of type `Emp2` which have different salaries with your code ...

Comment: How many Java classes have you written so far without a `public static void main` in them?  If this is all new to you, give it time and things like this will make sense as you work through more complex and real-world scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

Constructors allows more complex initialization of fields, that could go far beyond simple assignment.

Comment: Especially if you want to give parameters and use them to initialize your class.